# Install package without adding repository

Tags: ubuntu, packages

I have a clean Ubuntu 18.04 install.

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

returns

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

I want to install the `molly-guard` package, but that one resides in the `universe` repository ( https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/admin/molly-guard ).

I could modify `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contain the following

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

then issue an `apt update` and then `apt install molly-guard`.

I don't want to have access to the entire `universe` repository just because I install this one package.

Is there a way to install `molly-guard` without modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

- If yes, would there be drawbacks in doing it that way? For example, would the package not get upgraded during `apt upgrade`?
- What are the drawbacks of adding the `universe` repository just for this single package? Could it have any security implications? This will be a production webserver.

Answer (score 1):

The way to install this without changing your `sources.list` is to download the `.deb` file and install it locally using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/my.deb
```

The drawbacks are:

1. You are responsible for managing the dependencies for the package. If it requires other packages, you are responsible for locating, downloading, and resolving the dependencies of these packages.
2. You are responsible for checking the package (and it's dependencies) for updates and repeating #1 as needed when dependencies change.

The drawbacks to adding `universe` are that the packages in `universe` are not officially maintained by Canonical and are, instead, maintained by the Ubuntu community. If there are security related updates required for a package or it's dependencies in `universe` they may not be resolved as quickly. The need and timeliness of security updates is usually the only real concern in this space.